# Validating a list using Java8 stream

Tags: java, java-8

Lets say I have a `List<Foo>` objects and there is a `User` object inside `Foo`:

```
public class Foo {
   public User user;
}

public class User {
   int id;
   int typeId;
}
```

Lets say I have a method that takes in a User object and a List objects. Is there an efficient way in Java8 to stream the Foo objects and return fast if any of the Foo objects' User is not the same as the User passed into the method?

```
public boolean validate(User loggedInUser, List<Foo> objectsToVerify);
```

The idea I have is to do:

```
return objectsToVerify.stream().filter(o -> o.user != loggedInUser).collect(Collections.toList()).isEmpty();
```

Comment: use `!equals` instead `!=`

Comment: Don't use `collect(...).isEmpty()`. Use `findAny()`. And if you want "fast", i.e. faster than a `for` loop, you need to use parallel stream, though your list would have to be fairly large for it to be noticeably faster.

Comment: Why not use `anyMatch` then.

Comment: @JornVernee Good point. Depends on whether you want an example of an element that failed validation, for the error message. But since OP `validate()` method just returns `boolean`, `noneMatch()` is better.

Comment: @Andreas, Lets say I did want the results, how would I use anyMatch to collect the ids only efficiently?

Comment: @JohnBaum If you want all the mismatches, then your code is it. If you just want any mismatch, then `findAny()` is it. You can't use `allMatch`/`anyMatch`/`noneMatch` if you want the object, because they all return boolean.

Answer (score 1):

```
return objectsToVerify.stream().allMatch(o -> o.user.equals(loggedInUser));
```

should be what you are after.
Maybe with a proper `equals()` and `hashCode()` added to `User`.

Or if you want to use method references

```
return objectsToVerify.stream().map(Foo::getUser).allMatch(loggedInUser::equals);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is nice and simple with streams. Assuming `Foo.getUser` and `Foo.equals` exist, then:

```
return !objectsToVerify.stream()
    .map(Foo::getUser)
    .allMatch(loggedInUser::equals);
```

You mentioned 'fast'. This will return `true` on the first mismatch. If your list is truly huge then you could make the stream parallel so that it can be searched in multiple threads. But this is unlikely to be of any significance to overall performance unless there are millions of objects to verify.

Answer (score 0):

this should solve your problem :

```
return !objectsToVerify.parallelStream()
            .anyMatch(o -> !o.user.equals(loggedInUser));
```